# Dimensões do LinearLayout, definidas no java, não mantêm proporcionalidade entre resoluções

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tenho uma `View` no qual estou definindo programaticamente sua algura e largura desta forma:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linear.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 50;
params.width = 50;
linear.setLayoutParams(params);
```

No entanto tenho dois dispositivos com diferentes resoluções, e isso faz com que para cada dispositivo, minha `View` tenha tamanhos distintos definindo desta forma: `height = 50`.

Como faço para que minha `View` tenha um tamanho proporcional a minha resolução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que `height` e `width` de [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#height), quando definidos via java, são valores em pixeis.

Para que as dimensões se mantenham consistentes entre diferentes resoluções de tela deverá pensar em termos de *dp* e converter os valores para pixel antes de os usar.

```
    ......
    ......
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linear.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = convertDpToPixels(50, this);
    params.width = convertDpToPixels(50, this);
    linear.setLayoutParams(params); 
}

public static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Activity context){

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float density = metrics.density;
    return (int) Math.ceil(dp * density);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[De acordo com o site do Android, o ideal é você ter um layout para cada tamanho de tela.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
Porém, se você fizer só o xhdpi(2x) e o hdpi(1,5x), ele consegue ajustar para o mdpi(1x) e ldpi(0,75x) por causa da proporcionalidade. E dá menos trabalho do que tentar ajustar automaticamente para todas as resoluções.